# Using @import in Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm having an issue with using `@import` to load global variables and also for the purpose of `@extend` from other files.

Let's say I have a `settings.css.scss` and I want this available in all my files by using `@import 'settings';` at the top of each other `scss` file.

This works fine and I do get proper access to all my variables and stuff -- but doesn't this inject all the styles again to each file?

When I look at the source in the after-compiled version, I'm seeing the same style for a given class repeated 3-4 times in firebug, except it's scratching out all but one.

Is this repetitive bloat normal or am I doing something wrong??

Comment: It does inject the file many times in compiled `application.css`. If you need  to access variables & mixins from single file in other scss files you should make sure that this file get's incluced first. May also need to change default `application.css` to not include all files automatically but do it by hand